# Plugin de CRUD para Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Alguém conhece uma ferramenta (plugin) que permita se customizar CRUDS simples e acessá-los na interface do wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Não é uma interface, mas só apontando aqui que não é necessário nenhum plugin pra fazer CRUDs genéricos dentro do WordPress. O sistema usa uma classe global chamada [$wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) que já traz consigo uma conexão aberta ao banco, então é só usá-la como vc usaria uma instância de PDO, por exemplo.

Exemplo do Codex:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta
             WHERE post_id = %d
             AND meta_key = %s
            ",
            13, 'gargle' 
            )
    );
```

Da mesma forma que vc pode rodar consultas contra as tabelas padrão do WP (como no exemplo) você pode rodar contra qualquer outra tabela que esteja no mesmo banco de dados.

Comment: Nesse sentido tem uma explicação bem interessante aqui:

https://gist.github.com/ericjuden/5136638

Mas, de fato, estava querendo saber de plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Conheço pelo menos três:

- http://codecanyon.net/item/xcrud-data-management-system-php-crud/3215400
- http://www.dadabik.org/index.php?function=dadabik_crud_wordpress
- http://wpdatatables.com/crud-system-in-wordpress/

Recomendo ver as features se atendem teu caso (que você poderia ter detalhado um pouco melhor talvez). Eu gosto mais do wpDataTables

Comment: Nenhuma livre, certo?

Comment: de fato nenhuma dessas que mencionei é livre... como a pergunta não fez nenhuma especificação a esse respeito, achei que opções pagas também valeriam como resposta =)